# Generate PDF from .docx file. ERROR Cannot add Title in Header -PHPOffice

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf, phpword, phpoffice

Im trying to convert a word file using PHPWORD library in PHP Laravel. Actually everything is fine with all of the files. BUt there are few files making such issues. I debugged it and dont know.

```
Here is a piece of code that im using 
`$domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
//Load word file
$Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($path . '/' . $file_name.'.docx'); 
//Save it into PDF
$PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
$PDFWriter->save($path . '/' . $file_name.'.pdf'); `
```

Comment: Which version of PHPWord/PHPOffice are you using? Did you try an other PDF renderer? What is the exact error ?

Comment: i tried all nothing worked...latest version im using

Comment: send the exact error to be able to help